# How do I get the list of mutual friends on Facebook using their API?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I am trying to get a list of mutual friends of myself and another user but none of the API I found in the documentation works. Either I get some weird permission errors that I can only get my friends list and no other user or I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function friends_getMutualFriends() on a non-object in /home/app.php on line 27
```

Is there a standard way that is used to get the total number of mutual friends or at least the list of friend ids of my friend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok... This one gave me a real hard time. I managed to do this using the Facebook JS SDK. Here's the snippet just in case anyone else wants to do this:

```
    FB.api(
          {
            method: 'fql.query',
            query: 'SELECT id FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())'
          },
          function(response) {
            $.each(response, function(json) {
                console.info(response[json].id);
                        FB.api(
                          {
                            method: 'friends.getMutualFriends',
                            target_uid: 'INSERT ANOTHER FRIEND ID HERE'
                          },
                          function(response) {
                            console.info(response);
                          }
                          );
                return false;
            });

          }
        );
```

Comment: When you say "insert another friend id here", should that be the response[json].id ? What other id would it be?

Answer (score 5):

This will give a list of mutual friends:

```
$mutual_friends = $facebook->api('/me/mutualfriends/friendid');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working 2016/ JAN

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/[USER_FRIEND_ID]?limit=100&fields=context.fields(mutual_friends.limit(100))&access_token=[YOUR_USER_TOKEN]

The result is a Json with your common friends. Working in Graph v2.4 and v2.5 fine.

PS:
 if you searching for ALL_mutual_friend is friends without the same app instaled
 Mutual_friends -> booth users you from token session and another one in query have the app autorized.

new field in facebook user.context
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user-context/

(Use Graph Explorer to Test )

[image: facebook graph test mutual]

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. Though it is very late for answering question, it will help somebody. That's why answering this question.

`Legend` given answer is giving only mutual friends for friend. I have given solution which gives mutual friends of user(friend or friend of friend).

You asked `mutual friends of myself and another user` (not only friend) and in PHP.
So below is solution:

$source_id=current user

$target_id=friend or friend of friend

```
$query="SELECT uid, name, work FROM user WHERE uid IN 
(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = $source_id and uid2 IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = $target_id) ) ORDER BY name";
            $freinds_list=$this->facebook->api(array('method'=>'fql.query',
                    'query'=>$query));
```

Answer (score -1):

Well it's actually [friends.getMutualFriends()](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/friends.getMutualFriends).

**Have a play [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/friends.getMutualFriends).**

Comment: @Marko: That gives me the same error. I'm trying: `$mutual_friends = $facebook->api_client->friends_getMutualFriends(xxx,yyy);` where xxx is my id... Am I doing something wrong? Or could you give me a small example? The playground in the URL you pointed to gives me this error: `This API call could not be completed due to resource limits",`

Comment: Why are you using an underscore rather than a dot? friends**.**getMutualFriends

Comment: @Marko: I tried the other one too... I get the same error: 
`Fatal error: Call to a member function getMutualFriends() on a non-object in /home/app.php on line 27`. I included the `facebook.php` file that I downloaded from the website.

Comment: Which API are you using? The old REST or Graph?

Comment: @Marko: Hmm... Guess its the graphs API... So can this be done using this new API? I am not sure if I want to include both the old and new libraries...

Comment: @Legend: You're right others seem to be having the same issue.

Comment: @Marko: Oh boy so do you suggest that I revert back to the old one? Or is there a hack to just get the number using the old lib without actually using it as the main library? I cannot include both because it will then give me class redeclaration errors... Any suggestions?

Comment: @Legend the new PHP SDK supports both the graph and rest api.

Comment: @Nathan: Oh... Would you be kind enough to give me an example on how to do this using the new SDK?

Comment: Here is a good tutorial that will show you: http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/