# Android Facebook SDK: How to retrieve Mutual friends Graph API response

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I implemented this code from the Facebook SDK to get mutual friends.

```
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("fields", "context.fields(mutual_friends)");
        // make the API call 
        new Request(
            session,
            "/{user-id}",
            params,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    /* handle the result */
                    Log.d("results", response.toString());
                }
            }
        ).executeAsync();
```

How do i read the Response object and retrieve the total count and the list of mutual friends? I have successfully gotten the result in the log.
Thanks.

Comment: The response to graph requests are json encoded, so you should be able to use any standard json parser.

Comment: Hi Ming Li, if it is possible, can you kindly elaborate? Sorry im a beginner in Android and have no prior knowledge of JSON. I have tried this:

GraphObject go = response.getGraphObject();
JSONObject jso = go.getInnerJSONObject();
Object summary = jso.get("summary");
Log.d("summary", summary);

which returned null. Im pretty sure i did it wrongly, since i was guessing.

Would appreciate if you can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Booth people need autorize your friend_list_permission to you see the users in common. If not you need use all_mutual friends, but you just can run this in server, no working in clients. look documentation in all_mutual_friends.

I explain this post here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34663235/3516549